# How to limit objects an admin (without superuser) can interact with?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a platform and I thought using Djangos administrive user interface was simpler and faster than writing an own. The issue I have is that I don't want all admins to be able to see all objects, just the ones they are affiliated with.

I use my own created model called `Organisation` which basically is the affiliation.

I were reading this article: http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/09/30/django-admin-filtering.html but it seems old and outdated.

Because I copied the example and came up with this:

```
class QuizAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = QuizAdminForm

    list_display = ('title', 'category', )
    list_filter = ('category',)
    search_fields = ('description', 'category', )

    def queryset(self, request):
        """Limit quizzes to those that belong to the correct organisation."""
        qs = super(QuizAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        org = Organisation.objects.get(user=request.user)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(org=org)
```

But it seems like the queryset method never runs.
Is there another easy way to filter out the objects an admin user can interact with?

Thanks in advance for your sage advice and better wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That article is more than five years old, a few things have changed since then. But in this case all you need to do is call your method `get_queryset` rather than `queryset`.

Comment: Awesome, checked some different similar threads here on SO as well but didn't realize this. It works great! :)